# Selecting a value from Collapsible Panel Tab in Django

Tags: css, django, html

I have created the collapsible panel table and print the database values using HTML js css

```
class Venues(models.Model):
   venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   rent = models.IntegerField()
   parking_area = models.IntegerField()
```

now when i click on the a particular tab in it I want to pass the value for rent to a variable

Comment: i actual build it using dreamweaver so js part can in build it pretty long code

Comment: Unless there's some JS you want to show us, you can probably give up on getting some help. It's very relevant to your situation.